# Dúvida sobre carregamento de módulos com requireJS e angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end, requirejs

Estou estudando um código de um antigo funcionário da empresa e ele usou requireJS + angularJS. Ele criou vários módulos com bastantes serviços etc, porém, a minha dúvida é: ao utilizar um serviço ou uma diretiva, o require e o angular carregam todo o módulo ou apenas o serviço ou a diretiva chamada? Pq eu entendi as vantagens de usar require, porém não entendi como funciona na prática.

Comment: Podes colocar o pedaço de código aqui?

Answer (score 1):

O carregamento de módulos depende de como a aplicação está configurada.

Como a própria [documentação inicial sugere](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html):

1. Em desenvolvimento o *loader* carrega primeiramente o `main` e depois cada módulo no momento em que requerido.
2. Depois do desenvolvimento, na Internet, carregar cada módulo individualmente mataria completamente o desempenho de uma aplicação não trivial. Portanto é comum empacotar os módulos num único script maior e o adicionar preemptivamente da página, assim o *loader* identifica que os módulos já estão presentes e executa os scripts rapidamente.

Empacotar scripts para otimizar o carregamento da página é uma arte complicada. Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre isto [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138807/227).

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer sentido pense no seguinte:

Uma aplicação com vários módulos, vários controllers, diretivas, services, etc..

Se você não usar require, você precisa incluir todos os arquivos de uma só vez em sua view, usando RequireJS, você pode:

Separando cada módulo, service, controller, diretiva em arquivos separados, em seus respectivos diretórios, eles serão carregados apenas quando necessário.

Além disso, a sua aplicação se torna mais organizada, dado que você pode montar uma estrutura de arquivos de facil atendimento. E seus elementos podem ser reaproveitados, quando necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando com a resposta do @Pedro Laini eu também estou utilizando um load dinâmico, através do [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/).

Ele pode ser utilizando em conjunto com o seu sistema de rota, sendo carregado a partir de um resolve. Então digamos que você possua uma área administrativa com sistema de permissões, ele pode auxiliar ainda mais na segurança da sua aplicação, já que o módulo só será carregado se passar o resolve.

Além disso, como já dito pelo Pedro Laini, como os módulos só serão carregados conforme necessidade, o seu carregamento inicial será muito menor, dando mais velocidade ao seu app.