# Como obter o IP do usuário via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ip

Tenho três comandos que em conjunto retornam o IP do usuário. Queria transformá-los em um único comando com o comando `return`. 
Tipo assim:

```
return userip;
```

Como faço? Segue o código:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var userip;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Seu IP e:", userip);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Quais são os três comandos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pode usar uma função

Eu tentei assim, mas devido ao tempo da chamada contra o tempo da injeção do script externo não é possível obter de modo "síncrono":

```
function getIp()
{
   if (!document.body) {
      return false;
   }

   var d = document.createElement("script");
   d.src = "https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip";
   document.body.appendChild(d);

   return window.userip || false;
}
```

Pra usar é só chamar algo como:

```
document.write(getIp());
```

ou

```
alert(getIp());
```

O melhor é fazer *assíncrono* (assim ainda ajuda a evitar o [bloqueio de renderização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635)):

```js
function getIp(callback)
{
    function response(s)
    {
        callback(window.userip);

        s.onload = s.onerror = null;
        document.body.removeChild(s);
    }

    function trigger()
    {
        window.userip = false;

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.async = true;
        s.onload = function() {
            response(s);
        };
        s.onerror = function() {
            response(s);
        };

        s.src = "https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip";
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }

    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        trigger();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', trigger);
    }
}

getIp(function (ip) {
    console.log(ip);
});
```

Comment: @rafaelfranco4 estou tentando corrigir

Comment: Agradeço sua atenção!

Comment: @rafaelfranco4 o primeiro não funciona devido ao "runtime", os eventos trabalham paralelos, use o segundo por favor.

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme. Como uso o segundo exemplo?

Comment: @rafaelfranco4 com callback, assim `getIp(function (ip) {
    alert(ip);
});`

Comment: Muito Obrigado por tudo! Deu certinho!!!

Comment: marquei lá. Estava tentando descobrir como fazia isso! rsrsrs

Comment: @rafaelfranco4 Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para obter o IP do usuário do javascript é possível usar algum site qualquer, eu recomendo usar a **api** do IpIfy.

> https://www.ipify.org

Use o código da versão de JQuery ele é bem fácil que javascript normal, coloque isso na sua head primeiramente:

```
 <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Coloque exatamente isso em seu elemento de script para executar-lo, faça um pequeno teste primeiro. requer uma versão do JQuery atualizada ou velha.

```
$(function() {
 $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
  function(json) {
   document.write("Meu IP público é: ", json.ip);
  }
 );
});
```

Se sinta livre para testar o script com o que eu coloque abaixo. Lembrando, o site da api é um pouco lenta eu acho então... pode demorar uns 15 segundos para o IP ser atualizado, obviamente depende de sua internet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
          function(json) {
            document.write("Meu IP público é: ", json.ip);
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso essa API aqui: http://meuip.com/api-webservice-meuip.php

Muito simples, veja:

```html
<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://meuip.com/api/meuip.php');
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onload = function(e) {
    alert("Seu IP é: "+xmlhttp.response);
  }
</script>
```