# Aproveitar cache do navegador não funciona

Tags: htaccess, google, cache, pagespeed-insights

A ferramenta do Google PageSpeed está exibindo o erro:

> Aproveitar cache do navegador.

Meu site: buscaempresas.com.br.

Eu ativei em meu servidor os módulos `expires` e `headers`, depois eu adicionei no `htaccess` a configuração abaixo:

```
#Força a utilizar Cache-Control e Expires header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
 # Html
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
 # Data
 ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
 # Feed
 ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
 ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
 # Favicon
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
 # Media: images, video, audio
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
 # HTC files
 ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
 # Webfonts
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
 # CSS / JS
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript  "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
#Força o IE a sempre carregar utilizando a última versão disponível
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Mesmo assim o erro continua sendo exibido. Já testei diversas coisas mas não consegui arrumar esse erro.

Answer (score 2):

Os recursos que apresentam o problema são externos:

```
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (60 minutos)
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js?137237720 (60 minutos)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 horas)
```

Você não tem controle sobre eles, como eu disse nesta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124656/3635

Não tem como resolver, mas não é um problema grave de fato.

---

Já a outra mensagem de erro não tem nada haver com cache, o problema é no bloqueio de renderização:

> Remova o JavaScript de bloqueio de renderização:

Para resolver leia isto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211913/3635

Não é só um copy+paste, leia e entenda as propostas e aplique conforme necessário.