# Utilizar async="" irá resultar em um carregamento síncrono ou assíncrono?

Tags: javascript, async

Estou usando esta função para carregar meus scripts em uma única linha:

```
function loadJS () {
    for (var i = 1, max = arguments.length; i < max; i++) {
        var file = document.createElement("script");
        file.async = arguments[0];
        file.src = arguments[i]+".js";
        document.body.appendChild(file);
    }
}
```

Então eu faço assim no HTML:

```
<script onload="loadJS(true, 'js/carta', 'js/script')" src="js/load.js"></script>
```

O resultado está sendo:

```
<script async="" src="js/carta.js"></script>
<script async="" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Esse `async=""`, significa que irá fazer o carregamento de forma assíncrona ou síncrona?

Comment: Relacionada: [Sobre o atributo booleano defer e async vs otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46459/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `async=""` é assíncrono mesmo, ou seja não irá causar bloqueios de renderização e um script não irá esperar o outro, o que pode ser ruim se um `<script src>` depender do outro `<script src>`, no entanto é preferível usar o `async`, desde que saiba organizar, um exemplo que formulei:

- [O atributo “async” serve para executar scripts carregados dinamicamente? (AJAX)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211913/3635)
- [Eliminar JavaScript e CSS de bloqueio de renderização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635)

Segue o código:

```
//Esta função carrega os arquivos javascript
function loadJs(url, callback) {
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    //Verifica se o callback é uma função
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        var isReady = false;

        //Executa se for carregado no onload ou readystatechange
        function ready() {
             if (isReady) return;

             //Bloqueia execução repetida do callback
             isReady = true;

             //Chama o callback
             callback();
        }

        js.onload = ready;

        /*Internet explorer (http://stackoverflow.com/q/17978255/1518921)*/
        js.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (/^(complete|loaded)$/.test(js.readyState)) ready();
        }
    }

    js.async = true;
    js.src  = url;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
}

loadJs("js/jquery.min.js", function() {
    loadJs("js/bootstrap.js"); //Depende do jQuery
    loadJs("js/plugin.js"); //Depende do jQuery
});

//Não depende do jQuery
loadJs("js/outros-scripts.js");
```

Desta maneira vai usar o `async=""` para evitar o bloqueio de renderização e o callback só vai injectar os scripts que dependem do jQuery se ele tiver sido carregado:

```
function() {
    loadJs("js/bootstrap.js"); //Depende do jQuery
    loadJs("js/plugin.js"); //Depende do jQuery
}
```

### Diferença de defer e async

Existe já uma ótima pergunta sobre o respeito da ordem de declaração que pode ser interessante de ler também:

- [Ao usar async e defer, a ordem dos scripts é respeitada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85413/3635)

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> #### async HTML5
>
> A boolean attribute indicating that the browser should, if
>   possible, execute the script asynchronously. This attribute must not
>   be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts). If
>   it is included in this case it will have no effect.
>
> Dynamically inserted scripts execute asynchronously by default, so to
>   turn on synchronous execution (i.e. scripts execute in the order they
>   were loaded) set `async=false` See Browser compatibility for notes on
>   browser support. See also [Async scripts for asm.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Async_scripts).

Traduzindo:

> #### async HTML5
>
> Um atributo booleano que indica que o navegador deve, se
>   possível, executar o script de forma assíncrona. Este atributo não deve
>   ser usado se o atributo src estiver ausente (ou seja, para scripts em linha). E caso esteja incluído, não terá efeito.
>   Os scripts inseridos dinamicamente são executados de forma assíncrona por padrão, de modo a ativar a execução síncrona (ou seja, os scripts são executados na ordem em que eles foram carregados) set `async = false`
>
> Consulte a compatibilidade do navegador para obter notas no
>   Suporte do navegador. Veja também scripts [assíncronos para asm.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Async_scripts).