# Exibir css com file_get_contents para evitar o bloqueio de renderização

Tags: php, css

Estou otimizando um site (que já melhorou muito) e no PageSpeed Tools Insights do Google, diz que tenho que "Eliminar JavaScript e CSS de bloqueio de renderização no conteúdo acima da borda".

Deu certo fazendo assim:

```html
<style style="text/css">
  <?php
  /* Sweet alert */
  
  echo file_get_contents('js/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css');
  ?>
</style>
```

Com file_get_contents no PHP.
Mas as fontes, como esta:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/open_sans/stylesheet.css">
```

O file_get_contents não funciona.

Posso colocar o link das fontes no rodapé, mas o site carrega sem as fontes e não fica com uma estética legal.

Comment: Qual o texto resultado do echo?

Comment: Cara as fontes são umas das primeiras coisas que vc tem que carregar. ela tem que ficar lá no head mesmo. Vc pode testar fazendo um `include` para ver se melhora. Mas lembre-se que nem tudo que o Google fala nessas ferramentas é o ideal para todos os casos. No seu site a font faz parte do conteúdo "above the fold" pois aparece antes do primeiro scroll, então tem que vir logo no ínicio do documento mesmo!

Comment: Rogerio com style e file_get_contents vai ter que recarregar o CSS toda hora, vai consumir mais do servidor e ainda por cima vai perder a vantagem do uso do cache, para usar `<link>` veja a resposta que eu formulei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635 - seria assim `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></noscript>` (ps: em androids mais antigos que o 4.4 talvez não funcione então na resposta deixei uma solução de carregar o CSS com JS)